# Return undefined Redux store state in useEffect() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, state

My Redux store state return undefined in `useEffect` hook. If I remove empty array `[]` in `useEffect`, my Redux store return `true` value but very much and sometimes executed in an endless loop!

```
 useEffect(() => {
    store.subscribe(() => {
      setNodeProperties({
        positionX: store.getState().schemaViewer.positionX,
        positionY: store.getState().schemaViewer.positionY,
      });
        console.log(nodeProperties);
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: You need to provide specific value that you need to watch as the second argument to useEffect()

Comment: Read the documentation for useEffect - specifically around the dependencies array argument.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `setNodeProperties` will queue up the change for `nodeProperties` and it won't happen right away because it is asynchronous. So I would try to run a side effect once `nodeProperties` is changing. You can have multiple `useEffect` hooks in your component.

Try as the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(nodeProperties);
}, [nodeProperties]);
```

In this way you are capturing changes for `nodeProperties` and run the logging step only then. Suggested read is [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

I hope this helps!